# fabric deploy "mkdir -p" gives socket error "no such file or directory", but command works in ssh

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, fabric

I'm using fabric3 to deploy a django project to an ubuntu (16.04) server. The code includes making directories, if required, with `mkdir -p`. A code snippet:

```
from fabric.api import env, local, run
(...)
def _create_directory_structure_if_necessary(site_folder):
    for subfolder in ('database', 'static', 'virtualenv', 'source'):
        run(f'mkdir -p {site_folder}/{subfolder}')
```

When I run `fab deploy:host=ubuntu@my.site.com`, I get the following error:

```
[ubuntu@my.site.com] Executing task 'deploy'
[ubuntu@my.site.com] run: mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/sites/my.site.com/database

Fatal error: Low level socket error connecting to host my.site.com on port 22: No such file or directory (tried 1 time)

Underlying exception:
    No such file or directory

Aborting.
```

The directory that was generated is correct, and there is already this file structure, with a working web site, on the server. If I ssh into the server, `mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/sites/my.site.com/database` works with no error. Why does the command work in a ssh window, but not in a fabric script?

Details: Using an Amazon Web Services EC2 server, with default `ubuntu` user. App uses django, nginx, gunicorn, Python3.6. I'm following the book [Test-Driven Development with Python](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_automate_deployment_with_fabric.html) by Harry Percival. Deploying from Mac OS X.

Comment: Clearly a look at your hosts section is needed. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the key file's path having a space in a directory name. I had used a quoted pathname to accommodate this:

```
env.key_filename = '~/"Bad Foldername/aws/keyname.pem"'
```

Moving the key to a path with no spaces and eliminating the extra quotes worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was caused by the fact that the key file didn't exist at the given path.

The fix was to add the `env.key_filename` file at the specified path and it worked !